# Issue with Eloquent: Retrieving Entries Based on Multiple Conditions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship

I'm facing an issue while trying to retrieve entries using Eloquent that meet specific criteria involving filtering on two related models. The goal is to first select reservations with a "Checked-In" status and then further filter these reservations to only include those with associated receipts in the "UNPAID" status. However, I'm encountering unexpected behavior where, if a reservation has at least one unpaid receipt, all receipts are returned, even if some of them have a "PAID" status

```
$reservations = Reservation::select('reservations.*')
    ->where('status', 'Checked-In')
    ->whereHas('bill.receipts', function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 'UNPAID');
    })
    ->get();
```

```
$reservations = Reservation::with(['bill.receipts.foodOrders.food', 'rooms'])
    ->where('status', 'Checked-In')
    ->whereHas('bill', function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('receipts', function ($subquery) {
            $subquery->where('status', 'UNPAID');
        });
    })
    ->get();
```

Both snippets are supposed to retrieve reservations with a "Checked-In" status and filter out those that have associated receipts with a "PAID" status. However, the issue arises when a reservation has one unpaid receipt; in that case, all receipts are returned, regardless of their status.

I suspect that my approach might be incorrect or that there might be some unintended interactions between the models and relationships

I've tried multiple whereHas() or double checking the relationships. Everything seems look alright. I feel I am missing something

For this following code, I started with Receipts instead:

```
$receipts = Receipt::with(['bill.reservation', 'foodOrders.food'])
    ->whereHas('bill.reservation', function ($query) {
        $query->where('reservationStatus', 'Checked-In');
    })
    ->where('status', 'UNPAID')
    ->get();
```

It does work and perhaps this a much better practice in terms of intuition and readability since I essentially want to display Receipts. But I cannot shake the feeling that the same can be done when starting with Reservation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as expected, but when you are going through the relations, it will reload them without considering the `whereHas()` conditionals, or any other for that matter.

Do what you are already doing, but use `with()` to filter the relationships also.

```
// previous calls but dont call ->get() yet
->with(['bill.receipts' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 'UNPAID');
}])
->get();
```

Comment: Insane. Is there a better way to describe what's being done with your code snippet? You are eager loading and filtering? And perhaps a better way to describe my initial problem?

Comment: I think the first paragraph does that, but your initial query only loads Reservations, your conditions is only conditions for filtering. When you go through the data like so $reservation->bill->receipts->something; the ORM will load the bill associated from the reservation and then the receipts. Logically it is confusing, but how it works with the active record pattern.

Comment: The with snippet, simply states that when your reservation model is loading receipts from bills it should add this condition also. Continuing the conclusion that your first query only loads reservations. When you get to the bill to load reservations it does not know you initial conditions.

Comment: When I am eagerly loading data with with() including both "'bill.receipts.orders.food'" and "'bill.receipts' => function...", the data is correctly filtered, regardless of ordering. I would have thought that ordering matters. If the filtering is applied first, then I assumed "'bill.receipts.orders.food'" would reload everything again. Using DB::enableQueryLog(), the query is completely the same. I assume there is some sort of hierarchy system that is handled by Eloquent?